# How to backup some tables with data and some tables only schema PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, backup, dump

I want to dump a database.

I have three tables:

table1
table2
table3

From table1 i want the schema plus data.

From table2 and table3 i just want the schema.

How do i do that?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a valid PostgreSQL error message.

Comment: i resolved the problem with the "copy from stdin" using the parameter "--inserts"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get data from just a few tables:

> pg_dump myDatabase --inserts -a -t table1 -t table2 > backup.sql;
>
> pg_dump myDatabase --inserts -a -t seq1 -t seq2 > backupSequences.sql;
>
> **Parameters descriptions:**
>
> -a, --data-only             dump only the data, not the schema
>
> -t, --table=TABLE           dump the named table(s) only
>
> --inserts                   dump data as INSERT commands, rather than
> COPY

This is what i wanted :)

Thanks all!

Comment: Note that if you happen to be running pg <= 8.1 multiple `-t` args are not supported. You can get around this with multiple dump commands, but resolving constraint dependencies for rebuilds is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-pgdump.html), which has both schema-only and schema + data output.